# Mysql how to create an incrementing id for an existing rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table with one column with the values (3,5,7).

I would like to add another column for the id so that the table has two columns where the values are (id, val) = ((1,3), (2,5), (3,7)).

Is there any way I could do that?

Comment: you need to these column to the same table or to another table ?

Comment: Without knowing more about the requirements and desired end-results, see [ROW_NUMBER()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/41vLX9z3T191tqkFhyRWLT/0) example.

Answer (score 1):

When you change table with adding id as PRIMARY KEY and AUTO_INCREMENT, then incremented id`s will be created automatically.